# Get the end points of each bar in a highcharts column chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to create a bar chart with arrows at the end of each bar pointing to the next bar. For this, I need to know the coordinates of the end point of each bar. Please refer to the image below for more clarity on what I am trying to achieve. [image: This is what I am trying to achieve]

My approach right now is to get the clientX in each series[0].points[i] inside the chart object and add it with the plotWidth to get to the point where I need to render the arrow image. This doesn't seem to work right now as the arrows are rendered incorrectly. I have a fiddle here with my current approach. I am trying to achieve the 'X' at the end of each bar, now it comes somewhere in the middle.

Here is the jsfiddle for the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/qp90yx34/1/

Here is the code for where I am at right now -

```js
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      events: {
        load: function () {
          _.each(this.series[0].points, (point, key) => {
            if (!_.isUndefined(this.series[0].points[key + 1])) {
              this.renderer.text("X",
              point.clientX + point.pointWidth, //x
              point.plotY) // y
              .add();
            }
          })  
        },
      }
    },
    title: {
      text: '',
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false,
          format: '<b>{point.name}</b> ({point.y:,.0f})',
        },
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3', 'Test 4', 'Test 5']
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'column',
      name: 'Marks',
      data: [83, 72, 71, 63, 74]
    }]
  });
});
```

Comment: You should be able to change a little bit your x position so it will also take chart.plotLeft parameter (offset of your plotArea from left edge of the chart container) http://jsfiddle.net/qp90yx34/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should be able to change x position of your text inside renderer.text method:

```
      this.renderer.text("X",
          point.clientX + point.pointWidth / 2 + chart.plotLeft, //x
          point.plotY) // y
        .add();
```

In this method I added **chart.plotLeft**, which is a distance between left edge of the chart and plotArea.

I have also changed **point.pointWidth** to **point.pointWidth/2** because point.clientX is a pixel position of a column center.

Live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/qp90yx34/2/